# Pick up a number in the range and it dones't conflict with exist ones in bash shell

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

In bash, I have to insert a new record with a valid port number(1-65535) to MySQL, the exist MySQL table haves records with some random ports value already, how can I pick up a new random  port number and it does't conflict with the exist ports value in MySQL, any smart way to do this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a logic for that:

1. create a table with single column which has values 1 till 65535.
2. and then write a query to get the list of id's in new table which
   are not in your working table.
3. then select the first id from the result list.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with MySQL, how can I write the sql query to get the list of id's in new table which are not in my working table? thx :)

Comment: Oh, I found it, use subselect.